# SPFx: How to populate the dropdown with list names

Tags: sharepoint-online, cascadingdropdown, spfx

I am trying to create a dropdown in the property panel of a webpart with SPFx and I found this tutorial: [Use cascading dropdowns in web part properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-cascading-dropdowns-in-web-part-properties)

The problem with the sample is that is is using static data and I would like to know how to fetch the list names dynamically.

How can I do that?
Best regards
Americo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pnpjs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-sp-pnp-js-with-spfx-web-parts) library so you could get the lists easily.

```
sp.web.lists.get().then((items:any[])=>{
      console.log(items.length);
      //to do, bind to dropdown
    })
```

[image]